# Header HTTP apikey missing token authentication

Tags: symfony, token

I'm trying to authenticate users via ApiToken Authentication. The problem I'm facing right now is that I don't know how to retrieve the header Apikey just created that contains the token for the logged in user.

After I authenticate the user, I generate for him a token and then I tried to set in Apikey HTTP Header that specific token in order to use it in my api. But after I set it, when I try to access an url from api, the Apikey header is missing.

local.web.com/api/login

```
 public function loginAction(Request $request)
 {
   (...)
   $tokenUser = $serviceUser->generateToken($username);
   $request->headers->add(array('apikey' => $tokenUser));
   $response = new Response($request);
   $response->send();

   return $response;
 }
```

local.web.com/api/list/products

```
   public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
{
    $apiToken = $request->headers->get('apikey');

    return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
        'anon.',
        $apiToken,
        $providerKey
    );
}


  The HTTP Header Apikey is missing.
```

Any advice?

Comment: Was it even sent though?

Comment: Yes..but after I changed the url, it doesn't appear.

Comment: What "it"? Have you actually checked how the http request looks like?

Comment: Yes, and my apikey is missing. What's not clear?

Comment: What is the exact complete http request?

Comment: Well, I assume we re talking about the second request:D because in the first one I add the header apikey, and in the browser, it looks very ugly, but anyway contains the apikey: (I send to you only a part because I don;t know how to send it to you more prettier)

Comment: GET /api/user/login HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Apikey: H2qRsr8bmFI Authorization: Basic YWRpbmE6YWRpbmE= Connection: keep-alive Cookie: firefly_akamai="R1Mr5OwllZ6Ikj3XRA3LANcwX8wnDMCM3tE9MUVJmJktqNc3rwLKBGXC8iFCRTXTvfWsybxGAz0bAEe5HsGyc5881eOcBkc9PTGxZhwFaE4qAdmgKbnutW1vu+W7GDUvABlHiglaBxdUQpGXn1y1vTKeDVoHoeD7NH4jm+2gvIE="; firefly_general="eyJlcG9jaER1cmF0aW9uIjogMjU5MjAwMH0="; cX_LSP=csst%3D1496650918371; (etc)

Comment: and in the second request, the one important..well i cannot show you..because I'm using debug, but in headers on request object is not apikey header

Comment: so it's sent but on the other side it's not received? (I'm lost in what 1st and 2nd requests are)

Comment: Yes. If you can see in the code in controller, I took the request that is sent in login and I added the apikey header(after many tries I stopped here) and then I created a response from the request(in order to apikey to remain 'active'). But it's not..but it's ok the strategy of doing this?

Comment: Take a screenshot (blacking out anything you don't want seen) and add it as an image (imgur is easy) in the question.

Comment: What we want to see is the return request from the (presumably) browser.